# mongoose removing properties from object

Tags: javascript, json, mongoose

Looking for a way to remove object properties before sending them to the front-end.
Is there any reason why this is working:

```
var obj = {
    name: 'cris',
    age: 22,
}
console.log(obj) //output name, age
delete obj.name
console.log(obj) //output age
```

and this isn't:

```
User.findOne({ username: req.query.username }, function (err, user) {
    if (user != null) {
        console.log(user) //output all props
        delete user.salt || delete user['salt']
        console.log(user) //output all props
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`user` is a Mongoose document and not a regular object.

You can convert it to one using [`toObject()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject):

```
user = user.toObject();
```

Answer (score 2):

to use delete you would need to convert the model document into a plain JavaScript object by calling toObject:

```
User.findOne({ username: req.query.username }, function (err, user) {
    if (user != null) {
        console.log(user) //output all props
        user = user.toObject();
        delete user.salt || delete user['salt']
        console.log(user) //remove salt prop
    } 
});
```

also you can modify uses this

```
User.findOne({}, function(err, user){
  user.key_to_delete = undefined;
  user.save();
});
```

Comment: If you set a property to `undefined`, and then invoke `save()`, does it only save the changes for this single retrieved instance? (ie, not the actual document record in the DB?) *EDIT* I did try this and it does only affect the retrieved instance (very cool). The only thing for me is my password salt field is required, so when I call `.save()` it flags a validation error (but still returns my json data so I guess its all good)...I wonder what best practice is..seems like converting it `toObject()` after it's been snagged is best to take it out of mongoose but curious what others think..

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose is returning an instance of model and not a plain JS object you are looking for. The data you are looking for that can be accessed by using `user.toObject()`.

Answer (score 0):

The db.collection.findOne() method returns a **cursor**. you need to convert to object using toObject(). use user.toObject() and then delete and send it to client.